# Which is the suggested way to Localize self-defined View type in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, localization

Take the following as an example:

```swift
struct CardView: View {
    var name: String
    ...
    var body: some View {
        ....
    }

    init(...) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How to implement Localization on this???

So, from the following choices, which should I choose:

1. inside `init`:

```swift
init(name: String) {
    self.name = NSLocalizedString(name, comment="")
}
```

2. make `name` a `LocalizedStringKey`, and force every `string` type to convert
3. when calling init, use `NSLocalizedString` every time

???

I haven't found any relevant info on Apple's website, can someone provide more details or vote on this ???

Comment: Also why don't guys at Apple makes it that `Text(_: String) => Text(LocalizedStringKey(from: _))` ... I don't get it

Comment: you need to replace `var name: String` with `var name: LocalizedStringKey`